# McAfee security for Sharepoint 2010

Tags: 2010, anti-virus

I'm looking into some virus protection for my SharePoint farm.
I'm currently testing McAfee security for SharePoint 2010.
It works fine with a test 'virus' file and SharePoint gives the following error when I try to add this file to a document library.

The only issue I see is that the below error message is not very user friendly.
Can this message be customized and would you have to do this at the SharePoint level or is this an option somewhere in the McAfee software.

Other hints for AV scanning on item level at upload are welcome as well.

> Error Found
>   EICAR test file
>   This file cannot be saved to the document library. If you want to save this file to the document library, clean the file using alternative virus scanning software and try saving it again.

Comment: You can use this product: http://www.microsoft.com/forefront/protection-for-sharepoint/en/us/default.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

> Other hints for AV scanning on item level at upload are welcome as well.

In case you are using (or plan to use) InfoPath FormsServices make sure you test the following:

1. From your forms library, create a new form
2. Fill out that form
3. Attach the EICAR file (with the file attachtment control)
4. Save the form
5. Check if the upload was accepted, or if is was rejected.

In one of my last projects we found out that the McAfee AV do not block viruses that are base64 encoded.